# How to loop object inside an object inside an array?

Tags: php, api

I'm receiving this structure from an API:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'id' => int 1616
      public 'cover' => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'id' => int 90739
          public 'url' => string '//images.extapi.com/extapi/image/upload/t_thumb/co1y0j.jpg' (length=54)
      public 'name' => string 'Mortal Kombat: Armageddon' (length=25)
```

I would like to know how can I print all this values.

I'm trying this code:

```
$result = $extAPI->game($options);    
            
    foreach($result as $row => $games){

        echo 'ID: ' . $games->id . '<br>';
        echo 'Name: ' . $games->name . '<br>';         
        
        foreach ($games->cover as $cv) {            
            echo 'ID cover: ' . $cv->id . '<br>';
            echo 'URL cover: ' . $cv->url . '<br>';
        }

    }
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
ID: 1616
Name: Mortal Kombat: Armageddon
( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in bla bla bla
ID cover:

( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property 'url' of non-object in bla bla bla
URL cover:
```

Could you help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to add a `foreach` for the `$games->cover`, since it isn't a collection, you can just access the properties directly:

```
$result = $extAPI->game($options); 
foreach($result as $row => $games){
  echo 'ID: ' . $games->id . '<br>';
  echo 'Name: ' . $games->name . '<br>';  
  echo 'ID cover: ' . $games->cover->id . '<br>';
  echo 'URL cover: ' . $games->cover->url . '<br>';
}
```